# ng-init with dynamic data not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

ng-init with dynamic value is not working. Can anybody help me what I am missing here..! Thanks

```
 <input type="text" class="form-input form-control" id="defaultInputText" ng-model="details.emailAddr"
                                                     ng-init="details.emailAddr = accSummary.response.custName"  placeholder="yourname@email.com">
```

Comment: What is `accSummary.response.custName`. That's not something that retrieved using AJAX right? What sets that right now?

Comment: `ng-init` defines initial value once. I'm not sure that it will work with dynamic values as you want. What result do you want to achieve?

Comment: @arjabbar its a json data getting from the response

Comment: @valverde93 you mean ng-init wont work for dynamic data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @valverde93 you mean ng-init wont work for dynamic data? –  chandru 2 mins ago

No, Like Cirdec said, you will have to set that in your controller after the request has finished. Right now when ng-init runs, `accSummary.response.custName` doesn't exist. It doesn't try to rerun ng-init once the AJAX response gets back because Angular doesn't know that it's an AJAX response or anything.

Your controller in the end should look something like this:

```
$http.get('/my-url', function(accSummary){
  details.emailAddr = accSummary.response.custName
});
```

I'm not totally sure what `accSummary` is or what your server responds with.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And Angular executes `ng-init` before you get responce from the server

Answer (score 0):

If you need to initialize the scope, such as setting `details.emailAddr`, make a controller that does that.

From the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties
>   of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use [controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.